# Format hyperlinks that span multiple lines

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

I have an Access database (Screenshot is attached) in which the text of an editor is stored line by line in the DB (called StoryLine column). I have the problem that URLs are stored as hypertext "URL" display names. Sometimes only hyperlinks are displayed in one line and the "URL" goes over several lines and then the display name is displayed.

Thank you very much for your help and hints.

I have merged all entries (with Formula) that are assigned to the same entry (all connected texts have the same StoryID). The problem is that the formatting is completely lost.

Only the display text of the URL should be displayed, if it exists, otherwise the complete URL.

HYPERLINK "http://votetandem.org" votetandem.org

should be 
voteandem.org (formatted as Hyperlink)

and
HYPERLINK [enter link description here](http://newsletter.ticketcorner.ch/go/3/3JMT4VKV-3JM7Y4X4-3J%20F73AD7-1PNNZI.html?affiliate=TAN&language=it&referer_info=SN%20-TGS-andrea-pucci-TC-20190924-CH-it_62440)
Acquista ora i 
biglietti!

should be

Acquista ora i biglietti! (formatted as Hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the below should work for you;

1. Create a Formula and type the desired text and hyperlink using the HTML tag  like:

   [image]
2. Insert the Formula Field on the report. Right click on the "Formula Field" inserted on the report, and select "Format Field"
3. In the "Format Editor" window, select the tab "Paragraph".  For the option "Text Interpretation", select "HTML Text"

Note that the SAP Hyperlink text displayed above is the actual hyperlink and selectable by the user. In your case, it may be a matter of just doing option 3 from above on the required fields.  I don't know your current structure of the report to give you an exact answer.

**Concat Strings**

Create a formula with something as such.  I haven't tested this so it may need some tweaking.

```
if {Command_Main.StoryLinesK} in ['45','46','47', '48',''49] then {Command_Main.StoryLine} & "" & {Command_Main.StoryLine}
```

Comment: Hi Aleksandar,

Thank you very much for your answer. I have the problem that I don't know how to merge lines 45 to 49 (see screenshot) so I can set the HTML tags. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am not too familiar with the access database structure but if the lines from 45- 49 are recorded as seperate strings and all have different ID's, you could possible do something as I added above in my initial answer.

Comment: thank you very much, that works in this case, but I have no idea or solution how to solve this dynamically in other cases. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Aye that would be a problem.  The fact each URL is different there is no way you can identify it easily. You can check for when it starts e.g. http and when it ends but the end seems to be different for each URL.  Is there a possibility of amendin the access database to somehow get it on a single line? I never used access so not sure why its stored across multiple lines as such.